# How do I assign a pointer to a custom section that is added after compilation with GCC?

Tags: gcc, embedded, elf

I'm using GCC and writing embedded software for STM32.

How do I read a section that is added with `--add-section`?

I want to add a section into an `elf` and inside my program assign a pointer to point to data of this section.

For example:

```
extern char * ptr_to_my_section = &my_array;
```

Then I will compile a file `my_data.cpp` and inject it into a specific section `my_section`.

my_data.cpp

```
char my_array[] = "This is the custom data";
```

And finally I'll create the binary executable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Then I will compile a file my_data.cpp and inject it into a specific section my_section.

You *don't* need to use `objcopy --add-section` for this. You can simply ask GCC to put your array into `my_section` using  `__attribute__((section("my_section")))`.

To find the start of this section, you can use `{__start,__end}` symbols which the linker "magically" adds for you:

```
const char *ptr_to_my_section = &__start_my_section;
const char *end_my_section = &__stop_my_section;
```